# FormPage does not evaluate arbitrary expression

Tags: evaluation, interpreter, formpage

Why a `FormPage` that simply evaluates an input expression

```
FormPage[{"e" -> "Expression"}, #e &]
```

does not evaluate arbitrary input expressions?
It works with `2+2` and other few apparently random expressions, but most of the times it returns *"Input cannot be processed. Try again."*

**EDIT**: On Mathematica 11.3 (Linux) one example that does not work is `Range[3]` , but strangely enough `Table[x,{x,1,3}]` works. On wolframcloud not even `Table` works

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

Wolfram Support explained that the `"Expression"` interpreter type is implicitly `Restricted` to not allow 'side effects'. They agreed that documentation should be improved.

To avoid this issue you can use

```
Restricted["Expression", All]
```

**Original answer:**

It does not evaluate them due to security reasons / to prevent injection type attacks.

The failure has `"RestrictionFailure"` tag which means that it understands it is an `"Expression"` but it refuses to process it anyway. Details are not documented though.

```
Interpreter["Expression"] @ "DeleteDirectory" // InputForm
```

> Failure["RestrictionFailure", <|"MessageTemplate" :> Interpreter::**insecure**, 
>     ...|>]

You can use `ToExpression` instead but then it is your responsibility to deal which malicious input.

Why `Table` is worse than `Range`? I do not know but given `Table` flexibility it may be very hard to predict whether a given command will e.g. drain all your memory. With `Range` the syntax is more verbose.

Comment: `DeleteDirectory` actually works if given as input to `FormPage[{"e" -> "Expression"}, #e &]` , also `Run` and `ReadString` do work. On the other hand `Range` does not. Evidently it's not a security measure, it's rather nonsense behavior.

Comment: @Fortsaint 1. It is important to recognize that this is a restriction failure, not an interpretation failure. 2. Message name suggests the intention behind this restriction 3. Whether that restriction is handled well is a different story and not my fault.

Answer (score 1):

In a `FormPage`, `"Expression"` is converted to a `Interpreter["Expression"]` for handling the input string. So the question is about `Interpreter["Expression"]`.

**NOTE:This explanation is wrong.**
In fact, `"Expression"` (as it will be `Interpreter["Expression"]`) stands for mathematical expressions rather than wolfram language expressions(which stated in the docs).

For general wolfram language expression, this is what I am using:

```
FormPage[{"e" -> ToExpression}, #e &]
```

---

[A comment to the question]

In your statement `Table[x,{x,1,3}]` works, I think that's due to it's input as an expression instead of a string, so it's evaluated to be a list of numbers.

When I input it as a string, like this

```
Interpreter["Expression"]@"Table[x,{x,1,3}]"
```

or this

```
Interpreter["Expression"]@ToString@Unevaluated@Table[x, {x, 1, 3}]
```

it fails.

Comment: Indeed the doc (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/InterpretingStrings.html) states: "Expression" — an expression in Wolfram Language syntax.

Comment: @Fortsaint and bcegkmqs23, I have an official response now.